# PyPI pip setup.py with nested requirements

Tags: pip, setuptools, setup.py, pypi

My package depends on both numpy and statsmodels and I have them listed in my setup.py script under `install_requires`:

```
SETUP_REQUIRES = [
  'numpy', 
]
INSTALL_REQUIRES = [
  'numpy', 
  'statsmodels>=0.5.0', 
]
setup(name=DISTNAME,
  author=AUTHOR,
  author_email=EMAIL,
  version=VERSION,
  packages=PACKAGES,
  package_data=PACKAGE_DATA,
  include_package_data=INCLUDE_PACKAGE_DATA,
  description=DESCRIPTION,
  long_description=LONG_DESCRIPTION,
  license=LICENSE,
  url=URL,
  download_url=DOWNLOAD_URL,
  classifiers=CLASSIFIERS,
  setup_requires=SETUP_REQUIRES,
  install_requires=INSTALL_REQUIRES,
  scripts = SCRIPTS,
```

)

but whenever I run `pip install mypackage` it fails to install statsmodels because it says it requires numpy.

```
Collecting statsmodels>=0.5.0 (from mypackage)
Downloading statsmodels-0.8.0rc1.zip (9.9MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 9.9MB 217kB/s 
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-nkf7ym2k/statsmodels/setup.py", line 330, in <module>
        from numpy.distutils.misc_util import get_info
    ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Is there a way to have it install numpy first? Or check for inter-package dependencies?

Comment: perhaps worth noting: there is an open issue for this at `statsmodels`: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3207

looks like you could downgrade to <0.8.0 and it would work.